# Outlook 2010 changes server's name

Tags: domain-name-system, outlook-2010

Why my outlook automatically changes the server's name when I connect my pc in intranet network with its local name?
I should use outlook from intranet and from internet, so I inserted ad server's name a common name for both networks. Everything works from intranet and from internet, however, when I back to office and I connet my Outlook it changes the server name with its local name (and works properly). When I go out of office this name can not be resolved and I must manually change server's name with the public name.
How to prevent the server's name changing by Outlook? The server is an Exchange 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have configured your firewall to forward the MAPI RPC ports used by Outlook to communicate with the Exchange Server. This is not a secure nor recommended configuration!

Instead, you should be using Outlook Anywhere. This provides a tunnel over the secure HTTPS protocol back to the network, at which point the appropriate Client Access environment is accessed by *internal* not *external* FQDN.

Comment: I just configured my firewall to forward HTTPS port to OWA and it is working also with Office Outlook. Is it possibile?

Comment: Entirely standard configuration. Encapsulation of RPC traffic in an SSL sockets layer to get through firewalls is pretty common. You do, of course, need to update the Outlook configuration to ensure it points to the external FQDN of the Client Access Array, which tells it where the RPC proxy is when not on the network. If you want to check how it is working, then that will be through using Wireshark or some traffic monitor on the firewall itself to look at the HTTPS (TCP port 443) packets passing through as you use Outlook from an external connection.

Comment: I updated Outlook configuration to use external FQDN however when I use it inside my network this configuration automatically updates to internal name... so when I go outside I must reconfigure Outlook with external FQDN.